# Kendo mobile actionsheet used in kendo ui web with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I try to get the Kendo Mobile ActionSheet running in web application along with AngularJS.

As Kendo mobile controls are supported in a non-mobile environment, I was wondering, how I can "open/show" the actionsheet using the ng-click attribute of a button.

I can see the actionsheet (hidden) in the DOM by using following markup:

```
<kendo-mobile-action-sheet id="inboxActions">
        <li class="km-actionsheet-title">Monday Meeting:</li>
        <li><a href="#" k-action="reply">Reply</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" k-action="replyAll">Reply All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" k-action="archive">Archive</a></li>
    </kendo-mobile-action-sheet>
    <a class="reply"
    kendo-mobile-button
    k-rel="'actionsheet'"
    href="\#inboxActions"
    >Reply</a>
```

When I click on the button, I get routed to "root#inboxActions". But what I need is, to show the action sheet on that button click. Can I use

```
ng-click
```

and how would I access the action-sheet in that click event function?

`$('#inboxActions').data('kendoMobileActionSheet')` returns `undefined`.

Thank you,
devmon

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```
<button kendo-mobile-button k-on-click="actions.open()">Regular button</button>
<a class="reply"
    kendo-mobile-button
    k-rel="'actionsheet'"
    k-on-click="actions.open()"
    >Reply</a>
<ul kendo-mobile-action-sheet="actions" k-popup='{"direction": "left"}'>
<li><a href="#" data-command="view">View</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-command="rename">Rename</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-command="delete">Delete</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-command="perms">Set permissions ...</a></li>
```

Thank you,
devmon